# Adding background image to MDI form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I would like to request people to give me inputs on how to show a background image in a winforms MDI Application.

I understand that it is possible through the MDI form.

Any inputs on how to go about it would be welcome.

Thanks so much

Regards
bornagaindeveloper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Winforms doesn't give you direct access to the MDI client window.  You have to find it, like this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls) {
            if (ctl is MdiClient) {
                ctl.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.SampleImage;
                break;
            }
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Comment: Paste it in the MDI parent form's class.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the code, Winforms intentionally suppresses the BackgroundImage for *any* RTL window.  You'll have to subscribe the Paint method instead.