# how to change mdiparent form's background picture with a child form?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 problems:

1. I cannot change my main form background with a child form
2. When I set form sizes in .NET it doesn't have any problem but when I compile my app, sizes change. I didn't have this problem last week!

Comment: The two problems are very unrelated. You should've opened two separate posts, each more elaborated and detailed. First thing that people would say to #1: What have you tried so far? And to #2: Give example to what changes and when (plus, post your code - duh).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding background image to MDI form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596161/adding-background-image-to-mdi-form)

Answer (score 1):

The background area of a Mdi container is a control of type **System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient**. You can get it from Mdi containers’ Controls collection, then treat it like any other control. So for setting Mdi containers’ background image:

```
public Control MdiClient
{
  get
  {
    Control result = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)
    {
      result = Controls[i];
      if (result.GetType().FullName == "System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient")
        return result;
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
MdiClient.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("SomeImage.jpg");
```