# Graphics.DrawLine not drawing anything on MDI container client area.

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I am trying to enhance [this CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6338/SnapFormExtender-a-magnet-for-your-MDI-child-forms) called SnapFormExtender. This project extends MDIParent forms and "snaps" its child forms to each other and its containers edges.

The problem I am having with it is that it tries to "snap" child forms too often while moving forms within the MDI container causing the form to jitter when a user moves it near another form or the container edges.

To fix this I want to draw an outline of the forms possible new location instead of redrawing the form, and when the user is done moving/resizing the form I will then actually change the forms position.

My current issue is that it seems that I cannot actually draw a line on the MDIParent form with `Graphics.DrawLine`. Below is the method I use to try to draw the lines on the MDIParent. (To be as succinct as possible I have posted the entire code to http://pastebin.com/uBREMh5g for further review)

In the code below `parentForm` is set in SnapFormExtender when it is added to a form. It is the MDIParent that this class works with to snap its child forms. `Form form` is the child form, and `Point possibleLocation` is the new location of the form (snapped location) if the user were to stop moving the form "now".

```
private void DrawPossiblePosition(Form form, Point possibleLocation)
{
    float[] dashValues = { 2, 2 };
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Drawing possible position");
    using (Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 5))
    {
        blackPen.DashPattern = dashValues;
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Got a black dashed pen");
        using (Graphics parentGfx = parentForm.CreateGraphics())
        {
            int xLoc = possibleLocation.X;
            int yLoc = possibleLocation.Y;
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Got gfx object, drawing lines");
            parentGfx.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(xLoc, yLoc), new Point(xLoc+form.Width, yLoc));
            parentGfx.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(xLoc+form.Width, yLoc), new Point(xLoc+form.Width, yLoc+form.Height));
            parentGfx.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(xLoc + form.Width, yLoc + form.Height), new Point(xLoc, yLoc + form.Height)); 
            parentGfx.DrawLine(blackPen, new Point(xLoc, yLoc + form.Height), new Point(xLoc, yLoc));
        }
    }
}
```

This code executes with no error and displays all of the `Console.Out.WriteLines`. It is called whenever a child form is being moved within the MDIParent.

What I can figure, since all of the print statements are called is that either the MDIParent is ignoring my `DrawLines` or it is repainting itself so often as a result of a form being moved that all of my `DrawLines` are just erased once the child form moves a single pixel. But I don't think this is the case because I never see even a flash of the lines on the screen.

Is there a special time/method by which I need to draw these lines?

Or.

Should I override the MDIParents `OnPaint` method to optionally draw lines of the specified location/dimension if a flag is set, and set the flag and dimensions from the SnapFormExtender class?

Comment: Splattering pixels on the screen with CreateGraphics() is never not a mistake.  This one falls down sooner, you have to draw to the [MdiClient window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596161/adding-background-image-to-mdi-form/3596192#3596192), the one with the dark-gray background.

Comment: @HansPassant So, in the pastebin code (if you have reviewed it, or would) there is the method `GetMdiClientArea` in which the MDIParent's `Controls` are looped over until one of type `MdiClient` is found. This is the object I want to `GetGraphics()` from to draw with then?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that worked very well! One last thing, how would I erase the old lines when new ones are to be drawn? // Also if you want to make that comment into an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: If you are _only_ drawing this "possible position", you can precede the drawing with `parentGfx.Clear(parentForm.BackColor);`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott What about if I have a BackgroundImage for the MdiClient?

Comment: I have found `parentForm.Refresh()` but I feel like that might become slow as some point. Is there anything that would be better than that to redraw the `MdiClient` background?

Comment: `Invalidate()` is what you'd typically use to force a redraw.  Regardless, just change the color:  `parentGfx.Clear(Color.Transparent);`.

Comment: `Invalidate()` seemingly does nothing (all lines stay), and clearing with a transparent color completely erases the background image and makes the background entirely black. `Refresh` is the only thing that works though, as you'd expect it, calling it often causes the movement of the form to be slow.